# PHP comparison of multiple strings failing

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, comparison

Hello I'm creating a cinema blog using wordpress. I created tv episodes using serialized data with custom text boxes. My problem here is that when ever I unserialize the data I want it to display seasons, episode number, and plot. However since multiple episodes will have the same seasons, I didn't want duplicate season numbers to display multiple times. I use an if statement to get this done; however once in a while I get duplicate seasons as if it is 2 different numbers when it's exactly the same. The make sure it wasn't human error with white space or anything, I input the season numbers using a list box with numbers. Unfortunately I still have that problem.

```
foreach ($data as $item):
 if ($item['season']  !== $old_season) {
       echo  '<ul class="panel"><h2 class="title">Season '. $item['season'].'</h2>'.     
             '<li><h2>'.stripslashes(base64_decode($item['title'])).'</h2>'; $old_season = $item['season'];} 
           echo         '<p>Episode'. $item['number']. 'Aired'.stripslashes(base64_decode($item['airdate'])).'</p>'
                   .'<p>'.stripslashes(base64_decode($item['plot'])).'</p></li>'; 
 endforeach
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: is `$data` a multidimensional array?

Comment: @Norse Thanks for your fast response, no $data isn't a multidimensional array

Comment: Check your seasons when the duplicate comes up. Is there any pattern to it?

Comment: @RJHill not from what I can tell

Comment: @Norse stupid question here, could $data be considered a multidimensional array if it contains the season number, episode number, airdate, and plot?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($data)` and post the results here.

Comment: @phpdev i did the var_dump($data) as requested

Comment: @Craig "multidimensional array" is an array of arrays.  Your var_dump up there is an example of a multidimensional array.

Comment: @Craig what happens if you remove the type comparison from the if statement: `if ($item['season']  !== $old_season) {` becomes `if ($item['season']  != $old_season) {`?  You could also try wrapping each in a trim: `if (trim($item['season'])  != trim($old_season)) {`

Comment: @sennett Thank you for clearing that up for me

Comment: @sennett if ($item['season'] != $old_season) was the way I had it first and i just tried with trim and still no luck

Comment: @Craig I guess the only thing left is to var_dump in each iteration of the loop and examine what exactly the values are.  In fact, what is the order of the `$data` coming in?  Given your var_dump, season 18 headers would get printed twice, as a season 2 falls in the middle of all the season 18 episodes.

Comment: @craig, I agree with sennett on that. It doubles up because of the order that the seasons are in. How are you getting this data into the array?

Comment: @sennett There are 4 season 18 episodes 3 fall under one head and then season 2 prints with its episodes and then another episode from season 18 prints with a separate header. Sometimes if i double save, the correct episodes will all align under one head. The episode that is usually separated from the rest is usually the most recent one entered. Another thing is that if all the episodes are saved at once then everything works fine, the problem arises when another episode is added at a later time.

Comment: @craig I believe you're going to need to sort them...

Comment: @RJHill I believe that may be the right. At one point before I created a field for seasons, I used to sort each episode by the episode number and not the season. I don't believe I changed that since.

Comment: To everyone I just uploaded the entire process hoping to shed more insight on how the codes operate, to lead to a solution.

Comment: @RJHill You were right! It appears sorting it was the problem. It was sorting by episode number instead of season number. Still puzzled at how duplicate seasons were able to pass my if statement.

Comment: @Craig, because the way you had it set up, it would only work if all of the seasons were in order. It set the $old_season to the current season at the end so if we just looked at that variable you'd see a bunch of season 18 which wouldn't repeat, but then a 2 comes in and the $old_season is set to 2, so that when that next season 18 comes in it's not a match to season 2 and pops up again...

Comment: Sorry for that long explanation.

Comment: @Craig It was because `$old_season` was constantly getting overwritten in the if statement, wiping the fact that some season 18 episodes were previously printed.

Comment: @sennett Thank you, it all makes sense now

Comment: @RJHill Thanks for all the help and the detailed explanation it will help me for future problems

Comment: Hopefully you guys will be around if any problems should arise in the future

Comment: @Craig No problem. I posted the answer below for anyone who doesn't want to read through all of these comments for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do in this case is sort the $data array and the code you have there will work just fine.

```
if ($item['season']  !== $old_season) {
       echo  '<ul class="panel"><h2 class="title">Season '. $item['season'].'</h2>'.     
             '<li><h2>'.stripslashes(base64_decode($item['title'])).'</h2>';
       $old_season = $item['season'];
}
```

The problem is the code right here:

```
$old_season = $item['season'];
```

because it only works on sequential elements.